# where is the bug in this Clojure code?

Tags: clojure

I have this Clojure code:

```
(defn apply-all-to-arg [& s]
    (let [arg (first s)
          exprs (rest s)]
        (for [condition exprs] (condition arg))))

(defn true-to-all? [& s]
    (every? true? (apply-all-to-arg s)))
```

This is test code:

```
(apply-all-to-arg 2 integer? odd? even?)
```

=> (true false true)

```
(every? true? (apply-all-to-arg 2 integer? odd? even?)
```

=> false

```
(true-to-all? 2 integer? odd? even?)
```

=> true

My question is:
Why does the function true-to-all? return true (it must have returned false instead)

Comment: This question's been answered well already, but as a side point you might be interested in the built-in function [`every-pred`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/every-pred), which you could call as `((every-pred integer? odd? even?) 2)`.

Comment: @KrisJenkins Thanks for suggestion. I didn't know that function. But as I see, that function is more generic and slower than mine.

Comment: @Long HDi I don't see what the problem is with functions that are more generic. Creating functions that are as generic as possible is a big plus in functional programming, since they're more composable.

Comment: @NielsK yes, generally I am trying to make things generic too, but what is good enough is good enough, right? My function takes only 0.2 milliseconds, that every-pred function takes 2 milliseconds. The problem is I SELDOM need to apply a COLLECTION of functions on a COLLECTION of values. Usually, I just need to apply a collection of function on a SINGLE value. For example, if I want to validate an age, I will write a function like this (defn human-age? [n] (true-to-all? n integer? pos? #(< % 200))). It's more readable than the every-pred function. And it's faster.

Comment: If I want to apply a COLLECTION of functions on a COLLECTION of values, I will use every-pred. Isn't it better than using every-pred everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`true-to-all?` calls `apply-all-to-arg` with the single argument `s`. So you're not calling `(every? true? (apply-all-to-arg 2 integer? odd? even?)`, but rather:

```
(every? true? (apply-all-to-arg (list 2 integer? odd? even?))
```

So in `apply-all-to-arg` the value of `arg` will be that list and the value of `exprs` will be the empty list. Since `every?` will be true for the empty list no matter what the condition is, you'll get back true.

To fix this you can either change `apply-all-to-arg`, so that it accepts a list instead of a variable number of arguments, or you can change `true-to-all?`, so that it passes the contents of `s` as multiple arguments rather than a single list (by using `apply`).

Answer (score 2):

The default Clojure function that creates a function that applies several functions to one argument in parallel is juxt:

```
=> ((juxt integer? odd? even?) 2)
[true false true]

=> (every? true? ((juxt integer? odd? even?) 2))
false

=> (defn true-to-all? [a & fns]
     (every? true? ((apply juxt fns) a)))

=> (true-to-all? 2 integer? odd? even?)
false
```

If the functions you combine with juxt all take multiple arguments it works as well

```
=> ((juxt + - / *) 6 3)
[9 3 2 18]
```

Comment: nice, one vote for this. I like the "parallel" part of this function. But how do you know that it applies functions in parallel? (doc juxt) does not say anything about the "parallel".

Comment: Not parallel as in parallel / multi-core processing. More that you can consider the Clojure comp function to combine functions into one 'serially' (arguments are passed through multiple functions, like a pipe), juxt creates a function where the argument is passed through multiple functions separately, in 'parallel'. Internally, all calls are done after eachother though.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call `true-to-all?`, the parameter `s` is a list, so you are effectively calling `(apply-all-to-arg '(2 integer? odd? even?))`

Try defining `true-to-all?` like this:

```
(defn true-to-all? [& s]
  (every? true? (apply apply-all-to-arg s))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also defined your function like below to make it more clear.

```
(defn apply-all-to-arg [v & fns] 
       (map #(% v) fns))
```

As this makes the function definition clear that it takes a value and optional functions to apply to that value.

Comment: yeah, it's more elegant. I am trying to get my brain think functional.